# How to access redux persist data inside getserversideprops or getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

How to access redux persist data inside getServersideProps or getStaticProps.

I want to authenticate my user I just stored login information inside redux store also persist that reducer and I able to see that information.

but I am unable to get this information inside getServersideProps or getStaticProps for conditional rendering.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Redux persist stores the store state on the client-side. `getServerSideProps` runs on the server and therefore has no access to the persisted data, it only has access to the initial state of the store.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes after use this plugin `next-redux-wrapper` I got initial state

Comment: @juliomalves how can I achieve any idea?